# How to write a delete trigger in Oracle PL/SQL - stuck on identifying "matching rows"

Tags: plsql, triggers

I have a trigger I'm writing whereby , once I delete a row, I want to delete the corresponding row in the another table (which is `common_cis.security_function` ).

and the source table is `party.security_function`

Here are the columns in `common_cis.security_function` :

```
URL
SCRTY_FUNC_NAME
SCRTY_FUNC_DESC
IDN
CREATE_TMSTMP
CNCRCY_USER_IDN
```

Here are the columns in `party.security_function` :

```
UPDATE_USER_SRC_SYS_CD
UPDATE_USER_ID
UPDATE_TS
SCRT_FUNC_NM
SCRT_FUNC_DESC
CREAT_USER_SRC_SYS_CD
CREAT_USER_ID
CREAT_TS
```

What I have so far is :

```
delete from common_cis.security_function   CCSF

                                             where CCSF.SCRTY_FUNC_NAME = :new.SCRT_FUNC_NM;
```

Is this the right idea? Or do I use some kind of row-ID ?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use integrity constraints for that, namely foreign key constraint with "ON DELETE CASCADE" condition.
Here is an example, but check first is there tables in your schema with names that I used:

```
-- create tables:
create table master_table(
URL             varchar2(1000),
SCRTY_FUNC_NAME varchar2(100),
SCRTY_FUNC_DESC varchar2(1000));

create table detail_table(
SCRT_FUNC_NM   varchar2(100),
SCRT_FUNC_DESC varchar2(1000),
UPDATE_USER_ID number,
UPDATE_TS      varchar2(100));

-- add primary key and foreign key constraints:
alter table master_table add constraint function_pk primary key (SCRTY_FUNC_NAME);

alter table detail_table add constraint function_fk foreign key (SCRT_FUNC_NM) references master_table (SCRTY_FUNC_NAME) on delete cascade;

-- fill tables with data:
insert into master_table
values ('url number 1', 'sec function #1', 'description of function #1');

insert into detail_table
values('sec function #1', 'description', 1, '123abc');

insert into detail_table
values('sec function #1', 'description', 2, '456xyz');

-- check tables: first contains 1 row and second - 2 rows
select count(*) from master_table;

select count(*) from detail_table;

-- delete rows from first table only:
delete from master_table;

-- check tables once again - both are empty:
select count(*) from master_table;

select count(*) from detail_table;

-- clear test tables:
drop table detail_table;

drop table master_table;
```